# Is it possible to display the install actions in a list in Inno Setup?

Tags: installation, inno-setup

Is it possible to list the progress like it does in other installers?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can monitor changes in `WizardForm.StatusLabel` and `WizardForm.FilenameLabel` and add them to your custom list box progress view.

```pascal
const
  GWL_WNDPROC = -4;
  SB_VERT = 1;
  SB_BOTTOM = 7;
  WM_VSCROLL = $0115;
  WM_ERASEBKGND = $0014;

type
  WPARAM = UINT_PTR;
  LPARAM = LongInt;
  LRESULT = LongInt;

var
  OldStatusLabelWndProc: LongInt;
  OldFilenameLabelWndProc: LongInt;
  OldProgressListBoxWndProc: LongInt;
  ProgressListBox: TNewListBox;
  PrevStatus: string;
  PrevFileName: string;

function CallWindowProc(
  lpPrevWndFunc: LongInt; hWnd: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM;
  lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; external 'CallWindowProcW@user32.dll stdcall';  
function SetWindowLong(hWnd: HWND; nIndex: Integer; dwNewLong: LongInt): LongInt;
  external 'SetWindowLongW@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure AddProgress(S: string);
begin
  if S <> '' then
  begin
    ProgressListBox.Items.Add(S);
    ProgressListBox.ItemIndex := ProgressListBox.Items.Count;
    SendMessage(ProgressListBox.Handle, WM_VSCROLL, SB_BOTTOM, 0);
  end;
end;

function StatusLabelWndProc(
  hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
begin
  Result := CallWindowProc(OldStatusLabelWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  if PrevStatus <> WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption then
  begin
    AddProgress(WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption);
    PrevStatus := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption;
  end;
end;

function FilenameLabelWndProc(
  hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
begin
  Result := CallWindowProc(OldFilenameLabelWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  if PrevFileName <> WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption then
  begin
    AddProgress(WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption);
    PrevFileName := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Caption;
  end;
end;

function ProgressListBoxWndProc(
  hwnd: HWND; uMsg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT;
begin
  // reduce flicker
  if uMsg = WM_ERASEBKGND then
  begin
    Result := 1;
  end
    else
  begin
    Result :=
      CallWindowProc(OldProgressListBoxWndProc, hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  OldStatusLabelWndProc :=
    SetWindowLong(WizardForm.StatusLabel.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC,
      CreateCallback(@StatusLabelWndProc));
  OldFilenameLabelWndProc :=
    SetWindowLong(WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC,
      CreateCallback(@FilenameLabelWndProc));

  WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Top;

  ProgressListBox := TNewListBox.Create(WizardForm);
  ProgressListBox.Parent := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent;
  ProgressListBox.Top :=
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Top + WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Height + ScaleY(8);
  ProgressListBox.Width := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Width;
  ProgressListBox.Height :=
    ProgressListBox.Parent.ClientHeight - ProgressListBox.Top - ScaleY(16);
  ProgressListBox.Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  OldProgressListBoxWndProc :=
    SetWindowLong(ProgressListBox.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC,
      CreateCallback(@ProgressListBoxWndProc));
  // Lame way to shrink width of labels to client width of the list box,
  // so that particularly when the file paths in FilenameLabel are shortened
  // to fit to the label, they actually fit even to the list box.
  WizardForm.StatusLabel.Width := WizardForm.StatusLabel.Width - ScaleY(24);
  WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Width := WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Width - ScaleY(24);
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  // In case you are using VCL styles or similar, this needs to be done before
  // you unload the style.
  SetWindowLong(
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, OldStatusLabelWndProc);
  SetWindowLong(
    WizardForm.FilenameLabel.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, OldFilenameLabelWndProc);
  SetWindowLong(
    ProgressListBox.Handle, GWL_WNDPROC, OldProgressListBoxWndProc);
end;
```

[image]