# Prevent automatic proceed from Installing to Finished page and allowing going back to the Installing page to review results in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

This question is a follow on from [Is it possible to display the install actions in a list in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64587596)

I don't know the ramifications of this request, but is it possible to also implement the **Back / Next** buttons like the other installer? I understand that they would only function when the wizard is visible. I like the idea that the user has an opportunity to scroll the file list before moving on.

[image: Installer Buttons]

Like I say, I don't know the complexities involved with adding such a feature. Having **Back** is not too important to me. But having **Next** visible (along with **Cancel**) and enabled at the right time would be nice.

Comment: I personally don't find this behavior to be helpful and simply adds a (IMO) confusing extra step to continue or complete the installation. If you really need to see the file list, enable logging. Scrolling the list doesn't really add any value, IMO, because you can't copy/paste it anyway.

Comment: @bill the main thing is I like the list. Just a preference. And logging is enabled. The Next button is a variation I am considering.

Comment: IMO the extra click only adds confusion. Why do I need to click "Next" if the application installation is completed? What else is the installer going to do (I thought it was done)? Then I have to click again on the Finish button? Confusing UX IMO, and probably contrary to Microsoft UI guidelines. I would stick with the default IS behavior.

Comment: @bill. Ok I won’t add the next button just now. But I do like the concept. After all, it can’t be THAT BAD if competitors use that style. But that is going off topic and opinion based. 

Comment: All I see here is extra work for no real benefit; but to each his/her own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom page after the installation page and when it's activated, move all installation page contents to it:

```pascal
var
  AfterInstallPage: TWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  AfterInstallPage :=
    CreateCustomPage(wpInstalling, 'Installation done', 'Installation has completed');
  // ...
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if (CurPageID = AfterInstallPage.ID) and
     // Prevent re-adding "Done" to the ProgressListBox when revisiting the page
     (ProgressListBox.Parent <> AfterInstallPage.Surface) then
  begin
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Parent := AfterInstallPage.Surface;
    // prevent reanimating the progress
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max - 1;
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Position := WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Max;

    ProgressListBox.Parent := AfterInstallPage.Surface;
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Parent := AfterInstallPage.Surface;
    WizardForm.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Done.';
    AddProgress('Done');
  end;
end;
```

[image]

[image]